# Are iPhone cookies enabled by default?

Tags: iphone, cookies

Are iPhone cookies enabled by default when you buy an iPhone? I ask as I do not want to build any features for a webapp which require cookies if most users do not have have them enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are enabled for visited websites by default. In the settings app you can change the setting for cookies. What visited websites means is this (i think):

For example you buy a new phone or restore and visit youtube.com which is from google. google.com would maybe try to save any cookies to save your username and password ir anything  but can't, because you have not visited google.com before. Only youtube.com will be able to save cookies on your phone.

Comment: What does it mean by "visited" websites?

Comment: I guess that for example google.com cannot save any cookies unless you visit google.com

Comment: How could google save a cookie when google.com is not visited? Is there some sort of background task running?

Answer (score 0):

Note there appears to be a [bug](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-57382153-233/mobile-safaris-default-cookies-settings-changing-randomly/) in which this setting randomly changes to "Never".  I don't know what the trigger is; some people are claiming it happens when updating to iOS 5 but I think that's just a coincidence of timing for certain folks.

I just had this happen to me when I restored my phone from a backup; however the backup was only an hour or so old and it definitely wasn't set to "Never" in the backup.  I've been on iOS 5 ever since it released, and the cookie setting was definitely the normal default (1st part cookies only) until I did the restore last week.